# Implementing SpongyCastle BouncyCastle JCEIESCipher

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, spongycastle

i've been messing around with Spongy and Bouncycastle, yet cannot find a way to implement the Bouncycastle/Spongycastle JCEIESCipher to encrypt/decrypt a message.

Does anyone know how to use it in a basic manner? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's a link to the javadoc. http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html

Comment: I actually may have found the answer to my own question for those out there wondering. I'll keep stackoverflow updated

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, using code from:

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/ECIESTest.java

Enjoy friends